# Recursive least square algorithm estimation in system isentification

Tags: matlab, recursion, square, identification

I have a  `y_tr = (1+2*tr.^2+4*tr.^4+6*tr.^6+7*tr.^7)` and `y_te = (1+2*te.^2+4*te.^4+6*te.^6+7*te.^7)`

`y = θ1x1 + θ3x3 + θ5x5 + θ7x7 + θ8x8 t =1:1000` and `t_tr` is 700 and `t_te` is 300.

I want the RLS algorithm for this. can you help me?